# Can I use "from __future__ import" to overcome API changes for "sort" in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

The pandas API on the sort function has changed from pandas version 17 on, so that now you need to use `df.sort_values` instead of `df.sort`:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-api-breaking

For some reasons, I need to run the same code on machines with different pandas versions.

Is there a way to modify the code below in a way that "sort" or "sort_values" works with both pandas versions, using the `from __future__ import` statement?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,7,5], columns=["A"])
print df

df=df.sort_values("A")     # from pandas version 17 on
# df=df.sort("A")          # prior to pandas version 17
print df
```

Comment: Is there a reason a try except block wouldn't work?

Comment: `__future__` imports are for changes to the Python language itself, not for changes to libraries.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I think this is the correct answer which reflects the misunderstanding I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar to bphi 's comment, you could try using if/else:

```
#print(pd.__version__.split('.'))
#output: ['0', '20', '2']
# using an or statement here just in case you need to ultra-future-proof
# will check if version is above 0.x.x or greater than 0.17.0

if int(pd.__version__.split('.')[1]) > 17 or int(pd.__version__.split('.')[0] > 0):
    df=df.sort_values("A")
else:
    df=df.sort("A")
```

However, the try/except block as well (credit to bphi for this one):

```
try:
    df.sort_values("A")
except YOUR_ERROR_HANDLING_HERE:
# technically it is an AttributeError:
    df.sort("A")
```

Comment: While I was aware of that :-) and this is not exactly what I was looking for, it is nevertheless a correct answer.

Comment: Careful -- `sort_values()` *might* raise an `AttributeError` too (it depends on the function, of course).. So the try..except version would need to be something like:

def get_sort_values():
    try:
        return df.sort_values
    except AttributeError:
        return df.sort

Comment: Indentation got lost in the commend, but I hope the point is clear

Comment: @redShadow Great point! I went and checked version `0.20.`. it looks like the `sort_values` function will raise `ValueError`s. I did not deep-dive... but we might be safe!

Comment: @MattR sure, but what if there is a bug in sort_values, that causes it to raise `AttributeError`? :) Or for example, you pass it an incorrect type. Normally you would get an exception, and immediately notice you have a bug. But if wrap it in an exception handler like this one, you'll get  a (possibly surprising) different behaviour instead. This is one way hard-to-catch bugs are created :) (hence, my warning).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would probably be to have a single module, exporting functions that expose the same interface, on top of different versions of the library.

See for example what six does: https://github.com/benjaminp/six

In this specific example, you could do something like:

File: `compat.py`

```
import pandas as pd   # I guess..
# You also need to import "df", of course..

# Note that version numbers might be more complex than this
pandas_version = tuple(map(int, pd.__version__.split('.')))

if pandas_version > (0, 17):
    sort_values = df.sort_values
else:
    sort_values = df.sort
```

This way, from the rest of the code, you can just `from yourlib.compat import sort_values`.

Once you no longer need to support versions 0.17, just get rid of the conditional in the module.

You can even do more complex things, eg. backporting functions (be careful though! vendoring large chunks of the library this ways is probably not the greatest idea):

```
if pandas_version > (0, 50):  # Or whatever
    some_func = pd.some_func
else:
    def some_func():
        pass  # Copied from the newer version
```